# ASP.net gridview paging index disappear when i change the page index

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

this is my code : when i change the index of pager i get the right data but the pager footer disapear :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" PageSize="4" AllowPaging="true"     AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="id" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="eventRowStyle" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged">
```

Codebehind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridViewDBEntities model = new GridViewDBEntities();
            var query = from p in model.userTbls select p;
            GridView1.DataSource = query;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewDBEntities model = new GridViewDBEntities();
    var query = (from p in model.userTbls orderby p.id ascending select p).Skip((e.NewPageIndex) * GridView1.PageSize).Take(GridView1.PageSize);
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = query;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force your Pager to remain visible !

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    GridView1.BottomPagerRow.visible = True
```

BTW you have already defined pageSize and set Paging to true so i think this will do

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           BindGrid();

        }
    }
       private void BindGrid()
        {
            GridViewDBEntities model = new GridViewDBEntities();
            var query = from p in model.userTbls select p;
            GridView1.DataSource = query;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  //  GridViewDBEntities model = new GridViewDBEntities();
   // var query = (from p in model.userTbls orderby p.id ascending select //p).Skip((e.NewPageIndex) * GridView1.PageSize).Take(GridView1.PageSize);
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   // GridView1.DataSource = query;
    //GridView1.DataBind();
     BindGrid();
}
```

Removing `!IsPostback` will cause problems later if you have to implement some functionality where you have to edit grid or insert records , Either way better will be to create a `Bind` method and use it according to requirements .

Comment: i user GridView1.BottomPagerRow.visible = True  in my GridView1_RowDataBound but get error ==> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: now i user GridView1.BottomPagerRow.Visible = true; in my GridView1_DataBound handler ,now it show pager row but just show "1" that it not link and my another page index didnt show

Comment: i did it by this and get solved,my problem was i user ispostback in my pageload

Comment: @MohammadrezaJahankhah Have you removed `!IsPostBack` from your code ?